# Поиск минимального элемента в массива заполненного со Сканера

Tags: java

Без сканера если создавать массив и заполнить его числами то получается. А если заполнить со сканера то никак не работает. То есть всегда выводится 0. А вот максимум нахожу. В чем может быть ошибка?`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[input];

    int minValue = array[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        if (minValue > array[i]) {
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(minValue);`
```

Comment: Так вы в самом начале в него ноль записали `int minValue = array[0];`, то есть вы еще по массиву вашему не прошли, а минимум уже нулем забили.

Comment: я не понимаю что туда записывать. Тоже думал что ошибка в этом потому что максимум могу найти. А можете подсказку дать?

Comment: `if (minValue > array[i])` ==> `if (minValue > array[i] || i == 0)`

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Вы в самом начале в него ноль записали `int minValue = array[0];`, то есть вы еще по массиву вашему не прошли, а минимум уже нулем забили.
Чтобы не забивать ненужными числами минимум, вы можете его инициализировать элементом из массива заменив это условие

```
if (minValue > array[i]) {...}
```

на это

```
if (minValue > array[i] || i == 0) {...}
```

Как альтернатива, вы можете инициализировать минимум максимальным значением

```
int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```